# How to have the good local time with react Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm creating a countdown and he is working. the only thing i don't find is how to have the good local time ? I think i need to change something with the date.now() but i'm not sure

```
TimerDecibels = () => {
    return this.state.sport.clubs.map((element) => {
      // Set the date we're counting down to

      // Update the count down every 1 second

      setInterval(() => {
        // Get today's date and time
        var now = Date.now();
        var countDownDate = new Date(element.dateMatchStop).getTime();

        // Find the distance between now and the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds

        var hours = Math.floor(
          (distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60),
        );
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Output the result in an element with id="demo"

        this.setState({heures: hours});
        this.setState({minutes: minutes});
        this.setState({secondes: seconds});

        // If the count down is over, write some text
        if (distance < 0) {
          return this.setState({expired: 'EXPIRED'});
        }
      }, 0);
    });
  };
```

Comment: What do you mean by *good local time*?

Comment: @derpirscher    We need "Paris" time but we have 2 hours more on the countdown

Comment: What is `element.dateMatchStop`

Comment: @derpirscher it's the date in UTC for the end of the match on the database

Comment: I meant exact value and type. Is it a number (for instance the result of some `getTime()`) or a string representation of the date like '2020-09-03T12:34:56'. Be aware that a string repesentation of a date time is always assumed localtime, unless a specific timezone is given ( the results of new `Date('2020-09-03T12:34:56')` and `new Date('2020-09-03T12:34:56Z')` differ by 2 hours in CEST, first is localtime, second is UTC). If it's a number, how was it generated?